# How to access sqlite database from server in my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am new in iphone and i work a project in which required to put database on the server.
I take link on the server and create our table on the server.

i search on the net i find that below process.

The Client Side Application:

1) receive input from the user (or client app event)
2) generate SQL request
3) XML encode the request if necessary
4) pass the request to the web service

The Server Side application:
1) receive request 
2) decode (XML parse) the input if necessary
3) analyze the request
4) perform the DB query
5) XML encode the query results
6) return the results

The Client Side application:
1) receive results 
2) decode (XML parse) the results if necessary
3) analyze the results if necessary
4) generate DB query to update client DB if necessary
5) perform the DB query to update client DB if necessary
6) display results if necessary

but i have no idea to implement it please tell me anyone how i implement it?
or
is it possible this in my application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *cool kids* are using [RESTful Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) for this type of distributed application architecture. You need a team do do this successfully.